# why print statement return None, when we use method on the list in python

Tags: python, list, methods, reverse, nonetype

why does this code print None and

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
print(a.reverse())
```

while this will print a reversed list

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.reverse()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function reverse doesn't return anything, ence why you get a None

When you `print(a.reverse())`, you print the result of the function .reverse() on a, but reverse essentially modify "a" without returning anything